# How do i pass a variable via the url , changing the class of a dd and li based on variable?

Tags: html, tabs, zurb-foundation

I'm trying to build a site in foundation. I'm struggling with the next part.

First let me present a part of the code:

```
<dl class="contained tabs">
    <dd class="active"><a href="#contactForm">Neem contact op</a></dd>
    <dd><a href="#hoofdleiders">Hoofdleiders</a></dd>
    <dd><a href="#leiders">Leiders</a></dd>
    <dd><a href="#staf">Staf</a></dd>
  </dl>

<ul class="tabs-content contained">

    <li id="contactFormTab" class="active">
      <div class="row collapse">
        <div class="two columns"><label class="inline">Naam</label></div>
        <div class="ten columns"><input type="text" name="naam" id="naam" placeholder="Naam" value="' . (isset($_POST['naam']) ? htmlspecialchars($_POST['naam']) : '') . '" />
      </div>
      <div class="row collapse">
        <div class="two columns"><label class="inline">Email</label></div>
        <div class="ten columns"><input type="text" name="mail" id="mail" placeholder="jouwnaam@jouwadres.nl" value="' . (isset($_POST['mail']) ? htmlspecialchars($_POST['mail']) : '') . '" />
      </div>
      <div class="row collapse">
        <div class="two columns"><label class="inline">Onderwerp</label></div>
        <div class="ten columns"><input type="text" name="onderwerp" id="onderwerp" placeholder="onderwerp" value="' . (isset($_POST['mail']) ? htmlspecialchars($_POST['onderwerp']) : '') . '" />
      </div>

      <label>Wat wilt u zeggen?</label>

      <textarea id="bericht" name="bericht" rows="3">' . (isset($_POST['bericht']) ? htmlspecialchars($_POST['bericht']) : '') . '</textarea><br />

      <button type="submit" name="submit" class="radius button">Verstuur</button>

    </li>

<li id="hoofdleidersTab">
      <ul class="block-grid five-up">
        <li><a href="mailto:mal@serenity.bc.reb"><img src="http://placehold.it/200x200&text=[persoon]" /><br />Naam 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="mailto:zoe@serenity.bc.reb"><img src="http://placehold.it/200x200&text=[persoon]" /><br />Naam 2</a></li>

      </ul>
    </li>
    <li id="leidersTab">
      <ul class="block-grid five-up">
        <li><a href="mailto:mal@serenity.bc.reb"><img src="http://placehold.it/200x200&text=[persoon]" /><br />Naam 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="mailto:zoe@serenity.bc.reb"><img src="http://placehold.it/200x200&text=[persoon]" /><br />Naam 2</a></li>

      </ul>
    </li>
    <li id="stafTab">
      <ul class="block-grid five-up">
        <li><a href="mailto:mal@serenity.bc.reb"><img src="http://placehold.it/200x200&text=[persoon]" /><br />Naam 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="mailto:zoe@serenity.bc.reb"><img src="http://placehold.it/200x200&text=[persoon]" /><br />Naam 2</a></li>

      </ul>
    </li>
```

So the dd class "active" and the li class "active" , make the tab highlighted.

My question is, how can i make the class to change to another `<dd>` item (lets say the 2nd one) and another li id (lets also say the second one) (hoofdleiders) using a variable passed in the url?

This is a part of a contact form, and I want to be able to land people right where they need to be.

Comment: URL params / variables will likely come in as PHP: $_GET[ '<var name>' ];

Comment: you lost me there.......

Comment: The dd and li are now hardcoded active, i need them to be variable active based upon a string in the url , say contact.php?who=Hoofdleiders

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not recommend implement in this way. You should use a framework or a pattern like MVC to manage your code better. However, in your case, this maybe a simple and clear solution.

Store each tab in a separated php file with the same name as the tab, for example, the `staf.php` file will like this:

```php
  <ul class="block-grid five-up">
    <li><a href="mailto:mal@serenity.bc.reb"><img src="http://placehold.it/200x200&text=[persoon]" /><br />Naam 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="mailto:zoe@serenity.bc.reb"><img src="http://placehold.it/200x200&text=[persoon]" /><br />Naam 2</a></li>
 </ul>
```

The main `contact.php` will be like this

```php
<?php 
# list all available tabs
$tabs = array(
   'contactform' => 'Contact form', 
   'hoofdleiders' => 'Hoofdleiders', 
   'leiders' => 'Leiders', 
   'staf' => 'Staf',
);

# get the selected Tab from the url, if no tab is specified use the first tab
$selectedTab = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'tab');
if (!in_array($selectedTab, $tabs))
    $selectedTab = $tabs[0];
?>   
<dl class="contained tabs">
    <?php foreach($tabs as $name => $label):?>
    <dd <?php echo ($tabName == $selectedTab ? "class='active'" : ""; ?>><a href="#<?php echo $name ?>"><?php echo $label ?></a></dd>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</dl>

<ul class="tabs-content contained">
<?php foreach($tabs as $tabName): ?>
    <li id="<?php echo $tabName; ?>" <?php echo ($tabName == $selectedTab ? "class='active'" : ""; ?>>
        <?php require_once ($tabName . ".php"); ?>
    </li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

In this case, the `contact.php` and all php files of each `li` must be in the same folder and can call the `contact.php` file in a URL like this `contact.php?tab=staf`

Comment: could you elaborate on why your method is better, or better yet, why his method is not ok?

Comment: Yep, with my method, you can easily edit the list of tabs and the contents of each tabs via the `$tabs` variables and php files as well as maintenance your `contact.php` file . You can also decide what is default tab, what do we do when user just use the `contact.php` without any param. Another point here is that when getting the value of a param in $_GET, using the `filter_input` will help you avoid some security hacks (just **some**) :D

However, I think you should read about **MVC** to get a better way to implement a PHP application.

Answer (score 0):

If you dont want to loop through items you can use IF clauses to add active state:

```
<dl class="contained tabs">
 <dd<?php if(!isset($_GET['tab']) || $_GET['tab']=='contactform') echo ' class="active"'; ?>>
      <a href="#contactForm?tab=contactform">Neem contact op</a>
 </dd>
 <dd<?php if($_GET['tab']=='hoofdleiders') echo ' class="active"'; ?>>
      <a href="#hoofdleiders?tab=hoofdleiders">Hoofdleiders</a>
 </dd>
 <dd<?php if($_GET['tab']=='leiders') echo ' class="active"'; ?>>
      <a href="#leiders?tab=leiders">Leiders</a>
 </dd>
 <dd<?php if($_GET['tab']=='staf') echo ' class="active"'; ?>>
      <a href="#staf?tab=staf">Staf</a>
 </dd>
</dl>
```

I added `!isset($_GET['tab']) ||` to the first tab so that this tab is the default (if `$_GET['tab']` is not set).

Then for each `LI` add the same PHP:

```
<li id="contactFormTab"<?php if(!isset($_GET['tab']) || $_GET['tab']=='contactform') echo ' class="active"'; ?>>

...

<li id="hoofdleidersTab"<?php if($_GET['tab']=='hoofdleiders') echo ' class="active"'; ?>>

...

<li id="leidersTab"<?php if($_GET['tab']=='leiders') echo ' class="active"'; ?>>

...

<li id="stafTab"<?php if($_GET['tab']=='staf') echo ' class="active"'; ?>>
```

Comment: thnx, im going to disect what you did here :)

Comment: Hmmm after reviewing it, how does this change the li id of each item to get a "active" class?i get the part your doing here for the dd

Comment: See my edit, you add the same PHP code as to the DD elements to the LI's

Comment: just changing the dd into the variable part seems to be enough... can you explain to me why it does not matter wich li item has the active class?

Comment: nevermind, the content does not change with the tab active without the active class on the li , duh :) thnx man

Comment: If it helped you please mark this answer as your suggested answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you wan't do it rendering the page you can use PHP like:

```
<? if ($_GET['param_name'] == 'somecondition'):?>
<html do something>
<?endif;?>
```

Or you can make with jquery after the page render interacting with user actions:

```
function getURLParameter(name) {
return decodeURI(
    (RegExp(name + '=' + '(.+?)(&|$)').exec(location.search)||[,null])[1]
);
}
```

And you can use this function to get the parameter in url and make some logic on javascript / jquery to make some cool things. If you need something more let me know.